# How to load db2 dump data from the one db(remotly installed) to docker based db

Tags: database, docker, db2

I am new to docker concept. I have followed [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2express-c/) to start and able to install db2 under docker environment.

My questions are
1)i need to load data in to this docker based db2. Data dump is from the db2 instance present remotely  in linux machines.How can i load the dump from the docker db2 console?

2)every time i start docker quick start terminal i need to do all the procedure done in above link again. can't i just run db2 container and go to db2 console?

3) su - db2inst1(from link) is asking for password non of attempts to that password succeed(will give my machine admin password,db2 password etc).i need to restart or start again the process to go in to db2 container.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you and only found this article: https://usmansaleemblog.wordpress.com/2015/09/23/moving-database-schema-to-db2-docker-container/. The problem is that I have a dump file from my schema not an ".sql" file. Did you find any solution so far?